# Ellipsize not working for textview inside table row

Tags: android, android-layout

I am using Table layout. I have two(columns) text-views in table row. I want to apply `android:ellipsize="end"` at the end of the `textView`.

But it is not working for me, see the screen shot below. Please give me any idea, how to apply ellipsize to the `textview` inside a `table row`.

Here is the code :

```
<TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/linerLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_margin="10dip"
        android:background="@drawable/shape1"
        android:stretchColumns="2" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/TableRow1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="Product used for "
                android:textColor="@color/black_color" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/productusedfor"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:minLines="1"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textColor="@color/black_color" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/TableRow1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="Treatment for "
                android:textColor="@color/black_color" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/treatementfor"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:minLines="1"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textColor="@color/black_color" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/TableRow1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="Horse Name "
                android:textColor="@color/black_color" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/horsename"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:minLines="1"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textColor="@color/black_color" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/TableRow1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="Where "
                android:textColor="@color/black_color" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/location"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:minLines="1"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textColor="@color/black_color" />
        </TableRow>
```

[image]

Comment: instead of minLines use maxLines.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this

You have to use following property. Because textview width is `wrap_content` so it is going outside from the tablerow. So if you use this property then it will work: `android:layout_weight="1"`.

```
<TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/linerLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_margin="10dip"
        android:background="@drawable/shape1"
        android:stretchColumns="2" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/TableRow1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="Product used for "
                android:textColor="@color/black_color" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/productusedfor"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:minLines="1"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="fjdsngfksngfkfngkaklmngkldfmnkldgfnskldngkldnsklnghdnklgfnkdtgfndkgfn"
                android:textColor="@color/black_color" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/TableRow1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="Treatment for "
                android:textColor="@color/black_color" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/treatementfor"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:minLines="1"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textColor="@color/black_color" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/TableRow1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="Horse Name "
                android:textColor="@color/black_color" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/horsename"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:minLines="1"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textColor="@color/black_color" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/TableRow1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="Where "
                android:textColor="@color/black_color" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/location"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:minLines="1"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textColor="@color/black_color" />
        </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

It may work for you.

Comment: life saver! it's working ! but EditText cursor not working after clicking on it!

Comment: In my case I had to add android:shrinkColumns="2" to the TableLayout to get it working.

Answer (score 1):

//try this

`android:maxEms="9"` this attributes will do change you **maxEms** according to your length what you want to achive.

```
<TextView
                android:id="@+id/productusedfor"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:minLines="1"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:maxEms="5"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textColor="@color/black_color" />
```

Answer (score 0):

For a multiline TextViews I use `android:maxLines="3"` in every TextView that needs ellipsize.